# Multiple Tags in Layers PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a layer with rule-assigned tags, and I'm eager to augment the visualization by incorporating an alternative value stored in a variable named length.

I currently have three rule-based rules in place, and I'm aiming to add a new one that universally applies to all. This new rule should insert my variable length above the line. How can I smoothly integrate this into the existing setup?

```
def label_mid_line(self):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layer = project.mapLayersByName('CABOS_COMAC')[0]  # Assume que existe uma camada chamada 'CABOS'

    # Criar um novo sistema de etiquetagem baseado em regras
    root_rule = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(QgsPalLayerSettings())

    # Primeira regra
    settings1 = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    settings1.fieldName = 'Conducteur'
    settings1.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
    settings1.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.OnLine | QgsPalLayerSettings.BelowLine  # Coloca a etiqueta abaixo da linha
    text_format1 = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
    text_format1.setSize(10)
    text_format1.setColor(QColor('#6058a4'))  # Cor para Cable NULL
    settings1.setFormat(text_format1)
    rule1_exp = '\"Cable\" IS NULL OR \"Cable\" = \'\' OR \"Cable\" = \'NULL\''
    rule1 = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(settings1, 0, 0, rule1_exp)
    root_rule.appendChild(rule1)

    # Segunda regra
    settings2 = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    settings2.fieldName = 'Cable'
    settings2.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
    settings2.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.OnLine | QgsPalLayerSettings.BelowLine  # Coloca a etiqueta abaixo da linha
    text_format2 = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format2.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
    text_format2.setSize(10)
    text_format2.setColor(QColor('#4855b8'))  # Cor para Cable começando com '98'
    settings2.setFormat(text_format2)
    rule2_exp = 'left("Cable", 2) = \'98\' OR left("Cable", 2) = \'B4\' OR left("Cable", 2) = \'A2\' OR left("Cable", 2) = \'A3\' OR left("Cable", 2) = \'C6\''
    rule2 = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(settings2, 0, 0, rule2_exp)
    root_rule.appendChild(rule2)

    # Terceira regra
    settings3 = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    settings3.fieldName = 'Cable'
    settings3.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
    settings3.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.OnLine | QgsPalLayerSettings.BelowLine  # Coloca a etiqueta abaixo da linha
    text_format3 = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format3.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
    text_format3.setSize(10)
    text_format3.setColor(QColor('#db1e2a'))  # Cor para todos os outros casos
    settings3.setFormat(text_format3)
    rule3_exp = 'ELSE'
    rule3 = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(settings3, 0, 0, rule3_exp)
    root_rule.appendChild(rule3)
    
    # Aplicar o sistema de etiquetagem baseado em regras à camada
    rules = QgsRuleBasedLabeling(root_rule)
    layer.setLabeling(rules)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```